# Issue with reading japanese characters using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this could be a very common problem and there would be lots of solution already given. I am unable to find solution for my problem, can some one please let me know if there is any duplicate post, or how to fix it.

I need to read source data from file which has Japanese characters using Python. I am getting following error while running python code in unix:

"UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 181-182: ordinal not in range(256)"

Below is my looklike source file and python code :

```
bash-4.2$ more sourcefile.csv
"1411780","","ひとみ"
```

Pyhton code :

```
import csv

with open('sourcefile.csv', "r", encoding='UTF-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for lines in csv_reader:
        Col1 = (lines[0])
        Col2 = (lines[2])
        print(Col1)
        print(Col2)
```

Comment: Strange. When I run this code I don't get UnicodeEncodeError. I get `IndexError: list index out of range`. Are you sure the code you've posted here is the code you're running? Also, are you sure you should be using a delimiter of "\t", since it looks like your csv file is delimited by commas, not tabs?

Comment: Is your shell using a charset that supports Japanese characters?

Comment: yes, it can read and write japanese characters. I have another shell scrpt that read and edit csv file containing japenese characters, so might not be the issue of charset

Comment: Note the word "encode" in the error message. Reading the file isn't the problem, but re-encoding the value of `Col2`, since it appears `sys.stdout` is using Latin-1 encoding, not UTF-8.

Comment: so how can I switch between Latin and UTF-8 based on the data? as my same code may need utf-8 encoding for other data sets